# reshape cast function throws different results

Tags: r

I use two different datasets with same format to transpose by using cast function. however the outcome is different, can someone help? below is my console.

```
> str(test.t)
'data.frame':   12217 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ VIN     : chr  "HFC26205942" "HFC26172705" "FNC26031708" "HFC26215858" ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 1 level "COUPON_ID": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value   : Factor w/ 22 levels "A0","B0","C0",..: 18 13 NA 17 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
> test.t1 <- cast(test.t,VIN~value)
> test.t1[1:3,]
        VIN   A0   B0   C0   D0   E0   F0   G0   H0   I0   J0   K0   L0   M0   N0   O0   P0   S0   T0   W0   X0   Y0   Z0   NA
1 C26060288 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   E0 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 C26060396 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   S0 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 C26061050 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
> str(propack.full.t)
'data.frame':   313265 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ VIN     : chr  "NT31322055" "NT31315819" "E12079358" "E12125048" ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 1 level "COUPON_ID": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value   : Factor w/ 24 levels "A0","B0","C0",..: NA NA 2 1 1 NA 1 1 NA 1 ...
> propack.full.t1 <- cast(propack.full.t[1:10000,],VIN~value)
Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default
> propack.full.t1[1:3,]
        VIN A0 B0 C0 D0 E0 F0 G0 H0 I0 J0 K0 L0 M0 O0 P0 R0 S0 V0 W0 X0 Y0 Z0 NA
1 C26043349  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2 C26060102  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3 C26061202  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is because of this:

> If the combination of variables you supply does not uniquely identify one row in the original data
>   set, you will need to supply an aggregating function,

(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape/reshape.pdf)

In the second data frame, apparently there are rows where VIN-value pairs are the same. For these rows, cast doesn't know what to do because it needs an aggregation function. As you see in the error, it defaults to using `length`.

```
Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default
```

For the first data frame, this case doesn't happen and no aggregation is required, so you see different results.

I'm not sure what kind of output you want to have from here, but you should specify the `fun.aggregate` parameter of the `cast()` function accordingly.

If you just want to transpose the data.frame, you should consider simply using `t()` function.